# Prove that if $\frac{3^{n}-1}{2}$ is a prime number then so is n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How can I prove if $\frac{3^{n}-1}{2}$ is a prime number then so is n.
I tried concluding that $3^{n}-1$ needs to be in the form of 2×p (p is a prime number) so $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 3^n$ is a prime number, but I can't think of a way to prove that either.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B3%5En-1%7D%7B2%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime&p=1), there's the similar [Prime numbers of the form $(3^n-1)/2$](/q/454398), where the first part of its currently accepted [answer](/a/650301) uses a similar argument to that in this [answer](/a/4691844) here. The search also comes up with the related [Is there a Lucas-Lehmer equivalent test for primes of the form ${3^p-1 \over 2}$?](/q/1969009).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Hint*: if $n = ab$ is composite, then you can write $$3^n - 1 = (3^a - 1)(3^{(b - 1)a} + 3^{(b - 2)a} + \dots + 3^a + 1).$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).